# Put configuration files of my python package in /etc/<appname> and log file in /var/log/<appname>

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

I am working on a python package (linux only) and using distutils. I want to put the configuration files in /etc/ and log files in /var/log/ or another common destination for such files.

Setuptools sort of [recommends](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#non-package-data-files) using a custom script extract and copy data files where necessary. Should I just provide a script or is there a better way of doing this?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use your distribution packaging system, e.g. deb or rpm. Because destination of  additional data files generally depends of target distribution.

Comment: For Debian packaging, you can start here: http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging . For Fedora RPMs look at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python

Comment: Yes. I am ready to go that way. Distribution packaging systems support what I want to do right?